# Problem in understanding operation on color python

Tags: python, colors, pygame, pixel

I'm start learning pygame i buy a book, in this book i have this script:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

all_colors = pygame.Surface((4096,4096),depth=24)

for r in xrange(256):
    x = (r & 15) * 256
    y = (r >> 4) * 256
    print x, "      " , y
    for g in xrange(256):
        for b in xrange(256):
            all_colors.set_at((x+g,y+b),(r,g,b))
    screen.blit(all_colors,(0,0))

pygame.image.save(all_colors,"allcolors.bmp")
```

In this script we produce an image that contains all colors that our computer can produce,the only instructions i don't understand are:

1. x = (r & 15) * 256
2. y = (r >> 4) * 256

Someone coud explane me why he make this 2 operation. I know that are bitwise operator but i don't understand why he do that thanks :D .

Comment: Try executing it by hand on paper and see how the results relate to the values of `r`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the bitwise *And* operator. 15 is 00001111 binary. Hence `(r & 15)` masks the lower 4 bits of `r`. The result is in range [0, 15].
`>>` is the right shift operator. `(r >> 4)` shift `r` by 4 bits to the right. If `r` is a byte (8 bit) value, the result is again in range [0, 15].
`(r & 15)` are the lower 4 bits of `r` and `(r >> 4)` are the higher 4 bits of `r` (if `r` is in range [0, 255]).

The `for` loop

```py
for r in xrange(256):
    x = (r & 15) * 256
    y = (r >> 4) * 256
```

can be substituted by the following nested `for` loops:

```py
for i in xrange(16):
    for j in xrange(16):
        r = i * 16 + j
        x = j * 256
        y = i * 256
```

The surface has a size of 4096x4096. 4096 = 16*256. `x` and `y` are both in range [0, 4096).

Answer (score 0):

This is really confusingly written IMO.  What's happening is that `x` and `y` (which define the location in a grid on the screen) are derived from `r` by taking the upper and lower 4 bits of each possible `r` value, but this isn't really obvious and you shouldn't feel bad for not getting it as a beginner; the author should feel bad for writing tricky code and not commenting it.  :)

IMO if you're doing bitwise stuff it's better to represent the numbers as hex, since that makes it easier to visualize the shifts (e.g. if you multiply something by `0x100` in hex it's more obvious that the goal is to shift two hex digits to the left vs if you multiply by decimal `256`).  I also think it'd be better to have the outer loop go through `x` and `y` and generate `r` from those values, rather than doing it the other way around, since the math is simpler that way.

Here's how I might write that loop (using hexadecimal numbers, with comments).  I've also written it to be Python 3 compatible, but I think it ought to be backward compatible with Python 2 as well:

```
for x in range(0x10):
    for y in range(0x10):
        # x and y define a 0x10 by 0x10 grid on the screen.
        print(x, "      " , y)
        # Each cell in the grid has a unique 8-bit red value (r) based on its x, y.
        r = x * 0x10 + y  
        # Each cell is itself 0x100 pixels square with each pixel having a unique g, b.
        for g in range(0x100):
            for b in range(0x100):
                # g and b serve as both color values and cell-relative coordinates.
                # To get the screen-relative coords we add the x/y values for the cell,
                # multiplied by the dimensions of the cell in pixels (0x100).
                all_colors.set_at((x * 0x100 + g, y * 0x100 + b), (r, g, b))
        screen.blit(all_colors, (0, 0))
```